# Proposed change to the "Enzyme" tag wiki (excerpt)

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

The current [enzymes](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enzymes) wiki excerpt states:

> Enzymes are organic catalysts. Most enzymes are proteins, although a few are catalytic RNA molecules. Catalysts speed up the rate of a reaction by lowering the activation energy barrier and are not consumed in the reaction.

However, in the light of findings that suggest ["some enzymes work by preventing reactions that are not wanted rather than promoting reactions that are wanted"](https://www.newscientist.com/article/mg12717256-100-some-enzymes-may-work-by-negative-catalysis/), it would be prudent to change the tag wiki excerpt to something that is not in disagreement with these findings...but also doesn't wholeheartedly embrace them (until they've been soundly established).

Hence I propose a "neutral" tag wiki excerpt (of sorts):

> Enzymes are macromolecular biological catalysts that alter the rate of a reaction, and are not consumed in the process. Most enzymes are proteins, although a few are catalytic RNA molecules.

So, do I have the green-light to go ahead with this edit?

EDIT:

Based on @Jan's suggestion, perhaps it would be better to edit the wiki excerpt to include a *brief* definition and indicate conditions for usage. So, the improved version will look like,

> Enzymes are macromolecular biological catalysts that alter the rate of a reaction. Use this tag for question regarding enzyme kinetics, classification and action.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of course you can propose it. However, it should be rejected. What you have written could be the beginning of a great tag *wiki* — but at the moment you seem to propose it being in the *excerpt* (which is where your original quote is).

Tag wiki *excerpts* should **not** define the topic unless it can be reasonably assumed that most people don’t know it. They should instead define the *usage:*

> Use this tag for questions on the catalytic effects of enzymes. It should not be used if the question could equally be asked for an inorganic or organic catalyst — in this case, *catalysis* may be more appropriate.

Comment: I've edited the post...hopefully for the better. [Unrelated: And boy am I glad to see you! How'd the "thesis" go? >:D Also, if it wasn't obvious... Aaron Abraham = paracresol = paracetamol :D]

Comment: @paracetamol Well, magna ;)